# Copy and Paste Values Using Multiple Criterias VBA Excel

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop, copy

I'm having difficulties figuring out how to copy and paste using two criteria.

Essentially I have two columns as such:

| Currency (Column M) | Dollar Amount (Column N) |
| --- | --- |
| CAD | -5 |
| CAD | -10 |
| USD | 10 |
| USD | -20 |

Now, I need to copy and paste the negative values into two different columns as such:

| CAD (row = lastrow + 2, column = K) | USD (row = lastrow + 2, column = L) |
| --- | --- |
| -5 | -20 |
| -10 |  |

This is the code I currently have but its adding a space = i between each value:

```
lastRow = wsA.Cells(Rows.Count, "M").End(xlUp).Row

For i = 3 To lastRow
    CurrencyValue = Cells(i, 13).Value
    NumberValue = Cells(i, 14).Value
    If CurrencyValue = "CAD" And NumberValue < -0.05 Then
        Range("N" & i).Copy Range("K" & lastRow + i)
    ElseIf CurrencyValue = "USD" And NumberValue < -0.05 Then
        Range("N" & i).Copy Range("L" & lastRow + i)
    End If
Next i
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like the following perhaps, can be optimized further.

```
With wsA
   For i = 3 to lastRow
       CurrencyValue = .Cells(i, 13).Value 'note the period
       NumberValue = .Cells(i, 14).Value 'note the period

       If CurrencyValue = "CAD" And NumberValue < -0.05 Then
           .Range("K" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Value = CurrencyValue
       ElseIf CurrencyValue = "USD" And NumberValue < -0.05 Then
           .Range("N" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Value = CurrencyValue
       End If
    Next
End With
```